# OpenCV Image comparsion

Tags: opencv

Edit.. while testing earlier outside my backyard with to different images, I am getting some noise within the background, how could I remove this such noise so i am only picking up my dog?

[image]
[image]

```
 #Import Images
    Background_Image = cv2.imread('bck.jpg',0)
    Forground_Image = cv2.imread('dog.jpg',0)

    #
    diff = cv2.absdiff(Background_Image,Forground_Image)

    thresh = cv2.threshold(diff, 80, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)
    (_, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for c in cnts:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(Forground_Image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 4)

    cv2.imshow('Test',Background_Image)
    cv2.imshow('Test1',Forground_Image)
    cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Yes I have edited my Question, i would like to know how to compare both images and print out to console if they are the same or not the same not to sure how to tackle this section

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV already has some background substraction implementations, I think you'll be better off with them than with some hand-rolled solution.
Tutorial: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/db/d5c/tutorial_py_bg_subtraction.html

Generate the difference image, then either:

1. see if the count of non-black pixels is above a threshold
2. or find the largest continuous blob in the difference image and check if it's area is above a threshold (as you're working with lossy images, camera noise and possibly changed lighting conditions I suspect this will be better, but the simpler counting might be good enough under some conditions)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. really help.